# How to use flyway:clean on a database with foreign constraints?

Tags: flyway

I am new to flyway and just trying it out at the moment, I copied my db and am trying to run

mvn flyway:clean

I get the following error,

Could not drop object 'VIP_STATUS' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Is there something special I need to do to clean a db with foreign key constraints? My database is sql server. Flyway version is 3.0.3 maven plugin.

Edit, More info: I have multiple schemas with foreign keys across the schemas, so I thought adding the schemas to the configuration might help however it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean cleans the schemas in the order specified by `flyway.schemas`.

It should handle foreign key references just fine as long as you don't have circular references between schemas.

I've now fixed the docs as they didn't make this explicitly clear.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately they do contain circular reference across the schemas (not my design) :(. Oh well not a big deal, I have gotten around it by cleaning manually and once I have my dbs cleaned once and updated I think they should be ok moving forward. Thanks Axel.